# Traversing subfolder files?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have wrote a script to erase a given word from docx files and am at my last hurdle of it checking subfolder items as well. Can someone help me in figuring out where I am failing in my execution. It works with all the files within the same directory but it won't also check subfolder items right now. Thanks for your help.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# Search and Replace all docx

import os, docx

from docx import Document


findText = input("Type text to replace: ")                              

#replaceText = input('What text would you like to replace it with: ')    


for dirs, folders, files in os.walk('.'):
    for subDirs in dirs:
        print('The Sub is ' + subDirs)
        for fileNames in files:
            print(subDirs + fileNames)
            if fileNames.endswith('.docx'):
                newDirName = os.path.abspath(subDirs)
                fileLocation = subDirs + '\\' + fileNames
                document = docx.Document(fileLocation)
                print('Document is:' + fileLocation)

                tables = document.tables
                for table in tables:
                    for row in table.rows:
                        for cell in row.cells:
                            for paragraph in cell.paragraphs:
                                if findText in paragraph.text:                              
                                    inline = paragraph.runs                                 
                                    for i in range(len(inline)):
                                        if findText in inline[i].text:
                                            text = inline[i].text.replace(findText, '')
                                            inline[i].text = text

                for paragraph in document.paragraphs:                           
                    if findText in paragraph.text:                              
                        inline = paragraph.runs                                 
                        for i in range(len(inline)):
                            if findText in inline[i].text:
                                text = inline[i].text.replace(findText, '')
                                inline[i].text = text

                document.save(fileLocation)
```

Comment: You say _it won't also check subfolder items_ - does that mean the actual docx processing is irrelevant. Can you trim that sample down to something small that still fails but doesn't give us eye strain?!

Comment: `os.walk` walks the tree so you likely don't need `for subDirs in dirs:` which just does a second tour of the subdirectories.

Comment: `dirs` will be a string, the current directory, so you are iterating over the individual characters in a the string when you do `for subDirs in dirs`.

Comment: Thank you guys for your advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[os.walk](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) iterates through subdirectories yielding a 3-tuple `(dirpath, dirnames, filenames)` for each subdirectory visited. When you do:

```
for dirs, folders, files in os.walk('.'):
    for subDirs in dirs:
```

things go badly wrong. `dirs` is the name of the subdirectory in each iteration which means that `for subDirs in dirs:` is really enumerating the characters in the directory name. It so happens that the first directory you iterate is `"."` and just by luck its a single character directory name so your for loop appears to work.

As soon as you walk into another subdirectory (lets call it 'foo'), your code will try to find subdirectories called `foo\f`, `foo\o` and `foo\o` a second time. That doesn't work.

But you shouldn't be re-enumerating the subdirectories yourself. `os.walk` already does that. Boiling your code down to the enumeration part, this will find all of the `.docx` in the subtree.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('.'):
    docx_files = [fn for fn in filenames if fn.endswith('.docx')]
    for docx_file in docx_files:
        filename = os.path.join(dirpath, docx_file)
        print(filename)
```

Comment: Hey tdelany, that was a amazing explanation and it worked perfectly. Apologies for the eye strain. Your solution was such an elegant method. If you don't mind can you break down the for basename line. It seemed like you had multiple lines of my code and did it all in one. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I expanded the operation and used sensible names.

Comment: Have no idea what that is but atleast I know what to look up...ha. Again, thanks a lot. This was for work so it'll save me a lot of time.